# If browser narrower than X, switch to mobile view?

Tags: css

For various reasons, I am creating a site (not online yet) that has separate pages for mobile. I want to add something to the "monitor" site which says "if the browser width is less than X pixels, view *mobilepagename.html instead of this page. What code can I add to the main site CSS to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't switch pages with only CSS. You can do media queries to change styling based on screen size though.

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 'px' ) and ( max-width: 'px') {
  /* Mobile Styles */
}
```

Or you can use

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 'px' ) {
  /* Mobile Styles */
}
```

`max-width` and `min-width` don't need to be in pixels either. You can use a variety of units like `vw`, `em`, etc.

If you want to switch pages based on screen size you'll need to use Javascript.

```
if ( window.outerWidth < x ) { 
    window.location = 'newpage.html'; 
}
```

### Edit

Combine the above Javascript with a resize event.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {

  if ( window.outerWidth < 1024 ) {
    window.location = 'yourmobilepage.html';
  }

});
```

Comment: Worth mentioning [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) will help you alot :)

Comment: I'm afraid the above doesn't switch me to the mobile page. Assistance still needed.

Comment: @SallySlomzenskiMilo what about the above isn't working? Have you tried any of the solutions? If so, how did you implement them and what is failing?

Comment: I put the last 2 gray boxes' code within a javascript script tag - changed width and page name. Perhaps my lack of knowledge of javascript caused me to misunderstand.

Comment: You'll need to update your question with solutions you've tried as well as any relevant error output from the developer console.